# how to access objects in an array by a property of those objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So recently I had to check if a user had a certain plugin installed, which is apparently quite easily done:

```
if(typeof navigator.plugins['plugin name'] === 'undefined'){
  alert('Please install plugin')
}
```

This isn't surprising to me, I thought it just accessed the object assigned to `plugin name` of the `plugins` object. (like `plugins['plugin name'] = {...}`)
The strange thing is, if you `console.log` the `navigator.plugins` variable, it comes out as such:

```
>PluginArray
 >0: Plugin
 >1: Plugin
 >2: Plugin
```

So, these Plugin objects are accessible by using both `navigotor.plugins['Plugin name']` and `navigator.plugins[i]`!

My question is, how can I achieve something similar, so I can access objects of an array both by index (easy iteration and preserving array functionalities) and by a property of said objects (easy accessing by id or name)?

The navigator.plugins object has the `PluginArray` prototype, so I suppose this class it somehow overrides the `obj['index']` accessor and looks for the object(s?) that have the given index as their 'name' property, either by iterating when accessing, maintaining an internal array that maps the numeric indexes to the names ([i] = 'index')or an internal object that maps names to their index (.index = i).

So any thoughts on the best approach?

EDIT: as pointed out by [Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31786351/1969960), you can assign the same object to both keys (`arr[0] = arr[obj.name] = obj`) and this can work quite well **if obj.name is unique**, if it is not you risk overriding the key that was set earlier. Definitely a cheap and easy solution if you want to use something like a unique database index as second key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same behaviour that DOM collections implement; internally if the passed key is an int forward it to `.item()` if its a string forward it to `.namedItem()`.

The closest you can get currently to this is an ES6 `Proxy()` with very limited support;

```
"use strict";
let Plugins = new Proxy(
    [{name: 'pdf', mime: 'pfft/pdf'}, {name: 'swf', type: 'flash'}],
    {
        get: function(obj, prop) 
        {
            if (!isNaN(prop)) // by index
                return obj[prop]

            for (var k in obj) // lookup a name
                if (obj[k].name == prop)
                    return obj[k];
        }
});

console.log(Plugins);        // Array [ Object, Object ]
console.log(Plugins[0]);     // Object { name: "pdf", type: "doc" }
console.log(Plugins['pdf']); // Object { name: "pdf", type: "doc" }
```

Comment: interesting! Can't wait until this is fully supported in all modern browsers :) Giving it another day or so but this looks like an acceptable answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the same value to multiple properties:

```js
var obj = {};
obj[0] = obj.name0 = value0;
obj[1] = obj.name1 = value1;
obj[2] = obj.name2 = value2;
```

Comment: interesting point, hadn't thought of that! But with an object structure like {name: 'name', 'version': 123}, I can't have 2 objects with the same name, as that would override the key of the first one (i would assign to obj['name'] twice). Definitely an option if your object structure involves unique ids (like from a database) though!

Answer (score 0):

An Array is at it's most basic an Object extended with a magic `length` key - you can add any key values to it you'd like. Iterating through it becomes slightly more complicated if you want to see the keys, and setting anything that can equate to a number (ie `arr["1"]`) will equate to setting a number index of the array.

Comment: I understand this, you can make an array  `var arr = ["one", "two", "three"]` and then `arr.anObj = {...}`, and it will have the keys 0,1,2 and 'anObj'.

But that's beside the question, I am wondering how I can make `var arr = [{id:'2', name:'two'}, {id:'3', name:'three'}]` and then access that first object by both `arr[0]` and `arr['two']`

Comment: Ah - custom getters are per properly name, I can't think of anything for arbitrary keys - the best I can suggest is a ```set``` wrapper to set both index and key together - perhaps a custom subclass of Array with custom .push() etc in it ?

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.plugins` has a prototype `PluginArray`, which links to native code that translates plugin names to entries in the array.

Use `console.log(navigator.plugins.__proto__)` to see this.